# Password regular expression with character, number and punctuation

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression for the password, where conditions are like

**1. Password must have at least 7 but no more than 10 characters.**

**2. Password must contain at least one upper case letter , one lower
    case letter, one digit and a punctuation character.(e.g., a-z,
    A-Z,0-9,!@#$%^&*()_+|~-=`{}[]:";'<>?,./)**

I tried using: `^(?=.{7,10})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+|~=`{}:";'<>?,./-][])$`

But the punctuation section is not clear in explaination, when I tested in `http://regex101.com/`

The punctuation explaination seems broken, can some explain why and help me to complete this.

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/qE6oS6/8 ?

Comment: Any good reason why you are limiting to 10 characters?... Many security conscious people will have/want a 12, 14, 16+ character password.

Comment: @scunliffe good point and thank you, we will discuss about your point

Comment: @Suganthan since you are hashing (and salting (hopefully!!)) the password, there should be no reason to limit the upper character constraint of it.

Comment: @stuXnet I didn't get your point, can you be bit brief.

Comment: @Suganthan how are you storing the password?

Comment: @stuXnet As you mention, we are hashing and storing

Comment: @Suganthan then your hash will have the same length, regardless of your password - so there is no need to limit the maximum length of the password because of fixed column lengths in your database or something like that.

Comment: Ohh.. got., so you are telling like we can have least limit and can avoid maximum limit, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following one should suit your needs:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,./-]).{7,10}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/e4gvfx8M6B-2rPwH)

Don't forget to escape the backslashes in Java since in string literals. In other words, replace each backslash in the above regex by two backslashes.

If you don't want to allow spaces as well, simple replace `.{7,10}` with `\S{7,10}` (again, escape the backslash in Java).

---

Two reasons why yours was wrong:

- You did not escape the `[` and `]` chars in your punct class (syntax error);
- You have to put the `-` char either at the beginning or at the end of a char class. Otherwise, it will be interpreted as a special char. For example, `[A-Z]` matches any uppercased char between `A` and `Z` while `[AZ-]` matches either `A`, `Z` or `-`.

Comment: for the test string(1:-  **78tre48`12**,   2:-  **yuuyuyuyuyuy**,   3:-  **ad8\\\09+9**) it actually fails

Comment: Might be this is corrected version, can you please check If I am right or not `/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/-]).{7,10}$`

Comment: @Suganthan In those strings, you have no uppercased letter, while you asked for a *password [that] must contain at least one upper case letter*.

Comment: Yes, you are right, let me clearly test my "test string and the code that I have written"

Answer (score 0):

I'm crazy to write this regex:

To be simple to read, just use `!@#` as special characters, you can add other characters after `!@#` :

`^(?!\d+$)(?![a-z]+$)(?![A-Z]+$)(?![!@#]+$)(?![a-z\d]+$)(?![A-Z\d]+$)(?![!@#\d]+$)(?![a-zA-Z]+$)(?![!@#a-z]+$)(?![!@#A-Z]+$)(?![a-zA-Z\d]+$)(?![!@#a-z\d]+$)(?![!@#A-Z\d]+$)(?![!@#a-zA-Z]+$)[!@#a-zA-Z\d]{7,10}$`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qE6oS6/10):

```
^           
(?!\d+$)           // the password cannot be all digites,of course
(?![a-z]+$)        // the password cannot be all a-z
(?![A-Z]+$)        // the password cannot be all A-Z
(?![!@#]+$)        // the password cannot be all !@# 
(?![a-z\d]+$)      // the password cannot be all a-z 0-9
(?![A-Z\d]+$)      // the password cannot be all A-Z 0-9
(?![!@#\d]+$)      // the password cannot be all !@# 0-9
(?![a-zA-Z]+$)     // the password cannot be all A-Z a-z
(?![!@#a-z]+$)     // the password cannot be all !@# a-z
(?![!@#A-Z]+$)     // the password cannot be all !@# A-Z
(?![a-zA-Z\d]+$)   // the password cannot be all A-Z a-z 0-9
(?![!@#a-z\d]+$)   // the password cannot be all !@# a-z 0-9
(?![!@#A-Z\d]+$)   // the password cannot be all !@# A-Z
(?![!@#a-zA-Z]+$)  // the password cannot be all !@# a-z A-Z
[!@#a-zA-Z\d]{7,10}  // the password SHOULD be in `!@# a-z A-Z 0-9` and length 7-10
$
```

Comment: :O Explanation, please.. :)

Comment: @1337 update my explanation. BTW: To be simple to read, just use `!@#` as special characters, you can add other charater after `!@#`

Answer (score 0):

You dont consume your string at all.Add

```
.*
```

at the end to consume it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one

```
          ((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})
```

For practice

```
           http://www.regexr.com/
```

Comment: Why `{6,20}`? OP states: _Password must have at least 7 but no more than 10 characters_

Comment: ya.. it was an example... the first param is, must have atleast 6 characters and second param ...should not proceed more than 20 characters, you can change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Good base here too

```
([a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*_+=(){}[\];':",\.<>\/\?-]{8,38})
```

also for testing I like `https://regex101.com`